# Why Java lmax disruptor have a big latency in passing events through EventProcessors?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I have a ring buffer in my project, in which a lot of publishers will publish events(for example 500 publishers), and I have 3 EventProcessors which should process the events sequentially. All events should pass this way:

{A lot of Publishers} -> {UpStreamProcessor} -> {DownStreamProcessor} -> {logProcessor}

The problem is that I am losing a lot of time in passing events between publish and starting of UpStreamProcessor, and end of UpStreamProcessor to start of DownStreamProcessor.

For example, When I have 500 publishers, It lasts 1ms in average for processing in UpStreamProcessor and DownStreamProcessor, while it lasts 400ms between UpStreamProcessor finish time to DownStreamProcessor start time.

This is the piece of code for constructing ring buffer and processors:

```
SequenceBarrier sequenceBarrier;

receiveBuffer = new RingBuffer<>(
    MessageContext.FACTORY, 
    new MultiThreadedLowContentionClaimStrategy(inputBufferSize),
    new YieldingWaitStrategy()
);

upStreamAgentProcessor = new BatchEventProcessor<>(
    receiveBuffer,
    receiveBuffer.newBarrier(),
    new UpStreamAgent()
);
sequenceBarrier = receiveBuffer.newBarrier(
    upStreamAgentProcessor.getSequence()
);

downStreamAgentProcessor = new BatchEventProcessor<MessageContext>(
    receiveBuffer,
    sequenceBarrier,
    new DownStreamAgent()
);
sequenceBarrier = receiveBuffer.newBarrier(
    downStreamAgentProcessor.getSequence()
);

logMapAgentProcessor = new BatchEventProcessor<MessageContext>(
    receiveBuffer,
    sequenceBarrier,
    LogMap.getInstance()
);


receiveBuffer.setGatingSequences(logMapAgentProcessor.getSequence());

operationalExecutor.submit(upStreamAgentProcessor);
operationalExecutor.submit(downStreamAgentProcessor);
operationalExecutor.submit(logMapAgentProcessor);
```

Comment: All your timing sounds very long.  Are you sure it is milli-seconds and not micro-seconds? Are you sure all the code has been warmed up?  How many CPUs do you have? The more producers you have try to use the same resources the slower their access will be.  I would try to reduce the number of producers ideally less than the number of CPUs you have.  Have you corrected for co-ordinated omission?

Comment: Yes they are milli seconds, but 1ms is not so long, cause it is always 0 ad sometimes round up to 1ms. I have 4 CPUs. I don't know anything about co-ordinated omission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disruptor is design to handle messages which take 0.0001 ms If a 1 ms or even 0.1 ms delay doesn't bother you I would use a plain ExecutorService. If you are seeing delays or more than 0.001 ms, it is unlikely to be disruptor and the tasks you are performing are taking are too long.

Here is a good presentation on co-ordinated omission. http://www.infoq.com/presentations/latency-pitfalls The bad news is that if you have a bottleneck which slows the producer as you appear to, latency can be much worse than you are measuring.

Comment: And if I have processors which last about 1ms, which solution fits my project? Using Queues?

Comment: @saeed Just about anything fits, even JMS which is slower. 1 ms is 3,000,000 clock cycles which is an eternity to a computer.  I would use the solution which appears to be the simplest.  This doesn't solve your problem but it may help you work out what your problem is in more detail.  I suspect you are trying to force too many events through a slow consumer giving you poor timings. 1 ms is too slow if you have more than 1000 events per second and more than enough if you have 100 per second.

Comment: I can not load any flash entity on web cause of my internet constraints. I there any good document on co-ordinated omission ?

Comment: @saeed Gil Tene coined the term http://www.infoq.com/presentations/latency-pitfalls

Comment: @saeed If you are interested in these topics you might like to join the Performance Java User's Group https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/107178245817384004088